# Prevent "this" from being rewritten TypeScript compilation

Tags: typescript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer 1.5 and I really need the "this" variable not to be mapped outside. 
I know typescript does this for some [valid reasons](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript).

```
declare var Polymer: any;
var MyBehavior = MyBehavior || {};

MyBehavior.FormSubmit = {
    _setInvalid: (query, status) => {
        var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(query));
        elems.forEach(element => {
            if (status) {
                element.setAttribute('invalid', status);
            }
            else {
                element.removeAttribute('invalid');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Will get then mapped to:

```
$this = this; 
var MyBehavior = MyBehavior || {};

MyBehavior.FormSubmit = {
    _setInvalid: (query, status) => {
        var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(Polymer.dom($this.root).querySelectorAll(query));
        elems.forEach(element => {
            if (status) {
                element.setAttribute('invalid', status);
            }
            else {
                element.removeAttribute('invalid');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

See the this above the variable? This will break the code. If I could access the "this.root" or equivalent that'll do wonders. Is there a way to prevent TypeScript from moving the "this"?

P.S:  I just knew about PolymerTS! Unfortunately I can't get it to work calling behaviors from the Polymer object.

Comment: Even in javascript that supports arrow functions (=>) `this` works as if it had been captured.  If you want old-school `this` behavior, you need to use old-school functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice i'm not using an arrow function, but a regular function

```
MyBehavior.FormSubmit = {
    _setInvalid: function(query, status) {
        var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(query));
        elems.forEach(element => {
            if (status) {
                element.setAttribute('invalid', status);
            }
            else {
                element.removeAttribute('invalid');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

One of the ways an arrow function is different from the regular function syntax is that inside an arrow function the this key word is binded to the class/object.

To make sure the meaning of "this" will not change when translating an arrow function (ECMAScript 6) to ECMAScript 5 the typescript compiler uses the

```
var _this = this;
```

Trick, which is an old JavaScript pattern.

Comment: bam bam bam! That was it! Thanks a bunch! Wow. I didn't know that the arrow function is binded to the class/object. I've always thought it was a sugar-syntax shorthand for function(). So that explains why it was mapping it all the way up there!!!